# Apply JQuery only on fist level child of <ul> of a particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I select the link elements of only the parent from a list like this?

```
<ul class="catlist">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        <ul class="sublist">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can bind event to ul with class= "catlist" and not class="sublist"

currently I am doing this:

```
$('ul.catlist').find('li').click(function () {
    // doing something
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to handle the case manually

```
$('ul.catlist > li').click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('ul').hasClass('catlist')) {
        console.log('clicked')
    }
});
```

---

Another choice is to stop the propagation of the event from the inner `li` elements

```
$('ul.catlist > li').click(function (e) {
    //do something
});

$('ul.catlist ul').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use direct descendent selector

```
$('ul.catlist > li').click(function() {
    // Do something
});
```

OR, you can also use `children`

```
$('ul.catlist').children('li').click(function() {
```

Also, the event of the other descendent children `li`s need to be stopped from bubbling up, so that the event handler of the direct children will not fire.

```
$('ul.catlist > li li').on('click', function (e) {
    return false; // e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: What about propagation